# swift cannot change width of uiview

Tags: swift

i'm trying to make a "custom" progress using a simple uiview. Todo so i tried so change the width of the size of the view depending on the progress. I set the constraints to :

> width:0, align leading to safe area: 16, top space 10

and here is how i tried to change the view:

```
        let width  = self.a.frame.width
    testView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0 , y: self.testView.frame.height * 0.7, width: width,   height: self.testView.frame.height * 0.3)
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: "I set the constraints" That's the problem, isn't it? You cannot change the `frame` of something if you have configured it with constraints. Those two things are opposites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap this in an animation block.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    testView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0 , y: self.testView.frame.height * 0.7, width: width,   height: self.testView.frame.height * 0.3)
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

You call this animation based on the action code that you have not shared. 
Call this when the progress reaches a certain point that you have defined